# Can you use a tool to knock out block?

Tags: jenga

Are you allowed to use a tool such as a pencil or stick to help tap the block out from the tower?

Answer (score 5):

**No.**

From [the rulebook](https://tesera.ru/images/items/3324/jenga.pdf):

> Use only one hand

While it doesn't specifically give an answer to your exact question; you are only allowed to do things that the rulebook allows you to do; and the rulebook does not mention anything about being allowed to use anything other than "only one hand".

Comment: So, this one is forbidden: https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/388956/jenga-pistol ?

Comment: In the same way that placing a rook upside down is forbidden in chess, sure... It being against the official rules of a particular organisation doesn't mean you can't do it, it only means you're not playing the same way most people will be.

Comment: @Nij - it begs the question: "what do we mean by *upside-down*?"